# automatically login user if they are guest with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I've been handed off some code that for legacy reasons must keep using the Yii framework. Though when a user comes to a certain page as a guest I need the page to automatically log them in as a certain user. After browsing both the Yii documentation and here I have not found any solutions to this problem. Is what I am trying to do possible with Yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Behaviors to do this, probably [onBegnRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication/#onBeginRequest-detail). This will fire before every request is handled, and automatically log a user in if they're currently a guest

```
<?php
class BeginRequest extends CBehavior
{
  public function attach($owner)
  {
    $owner->attachEventHandler('onBeginRequest', array($this, 'handleBeginRequest'));
  }

public function handleBeginRequest($event)
{
  if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest())
  {
    $identity = new UserIdentity('known-user', 'known-password');

    // authenticate identity or not, up to you if you know which user should be logged in
    Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
  }       
}
```

Comment: Okay, I've read up on the Yii behaviours on their wiki (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/#hh1), and it looks like I need to do a call to attach the behaviour to the object, would this be something I call at the top of the specific page that is required to automatically login the user? Also as it is only one page where this functionality is required, if I place the login code at the top of the page, will it log in the user as well?

Comment: I create a behaviours folder in protected/components and create a BeginRequest.php file.  Then in your config/main.php add the following `'behaviors'=>array('onBeginRequest'=>array('class'=>'application.components.behaviors.BeginRequest'),),`  that code will run for each Request Yii receives, and if the user is already logged in, nothing to worry about

Comment: The $owner variable being requested is an instance of a model to attach the behavior to correct? I am just getting an error of CWebApplication not being defined when it runs. Though I am suspecting this has to do with the way the original dev has set up the framework.